# asp.net mvc - optional/default value for integer field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, integer, default-value, option-type

Say I have a viewmodel like so:

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 255)]
    public int Owner { get; set; }
}
```

The page is submitted to it's controller where I check if ModelState.IsValid, however it doesn't pass. Obviously, owner is required. Why is that? I thought the default value for an unassigned int was 0. If I debug the app and inspect the object that is sent to the controller, the value is indeed 0.

If I don't want to force the user to enter 0, what's the best approach? I've tried adding a [DefaultValue(0)] attribute to the Owner property in the class but it does not seem to do any difference.

Some guidance would be nice even if this is such a newbie or trivial getting-used-to-the-concept kind of problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Did you try making the Owner `int` a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) value?

```
[Range(0, 255)]
public int? Owner { get; set; }
```

Comment: this is not working for me - maybe the Range attribute is required?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if it's null before checking modelState:

```
if (viewModel.Owner == null)
{
  viewModel.Owner = 0;
}

if(ModelState.IsValid)
...
```